# Metal frame buffers on OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, metal

Soo, I came up with a problem after updating to Xcode 7.1 Beta 2 ( well, that didn't work before too ). Before I had this piece of Metal shader I took from Apple samples ( MetalDeferredLighting ):

```
struct FragOutput {
    float4 albedo [[color(0)]];
    float4 normal [[color(1)]];
    float  depth [[color(2)]];
    float4 light [[color(3)]];
};
```

And when I use it for color output/input it doesn't work, but after updating to Xcode 7.1 Beta 2 I even got the following error on OS X:

```
Fragment shader parameter with attribute 'color' is supported only on iOS (requires -std=ios-metal1.[0][1])
```

In Xcode 7.0 Beta it didn't even work, I just got black screen.

Is there any way to make frame buffer ( render targets ) work on OSX?